# Instagram custom search - filter by number of likes

Tags: instagram

I'm trying to understand how to build a page that retrives all the images from instagram, that used a specific tag, whit a minimum number of X likes. Current tool on the web doesn't filter for likes number.

I found things like instafeed.js but it seems that it's impossible to use them at the moment because of the new instagram api limits.

I think that it should be quite easy to do this, but I don't know how to proceed :/

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty straightforward but you have no code to go off in your question. What programming language are you using? You would ideally use their API for this. I'm not sure about limits though, which are you referring to?

Take a look at their docs

https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: Since it's really a one-shot use, I was hoping to find a resource which comes with preset functions and you just have to customize it basing on your needings. I know only PHP, would be hard to code it with just PHP I think, while it would be possible for me if there's any "ready to use" library or something likes this. Instagram developer tutorial is too much advanced for me.